# Json to Dart List

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to use this json for my project.

https://github.com/altafc22/csc_picker/blob/master/lib/assets/country.json

However, I don't want to use it directly in my project cuz it's a big file and want to specialize it a little bit. Is there a way to convert this json to Dart lists?

Comment: You should upload them somewhere, then use as an api, instead of storing it in the project directory it will increase the size.
Here I have available 1 class that works on dart suitable for your data:
https://pastebin.com/tqkiaquS

Answer (score 0):

**Try out this**

```
Future getResponse() async {
    var res = await rootBundle.loadString('packages/country_state_city_picker/lib/assets/country.json'); // Use your url
    return jsonDecode(res);
  }
  
  and fetch list like below:
  
   var countryres = await getResponse() as List;
   print(countryres);
```